# Postgres development on multiple machines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, synchronization, dropbox

Looking for advice on developing a Rails app using Postgres on multiple machines. Default sqlite3 has your development database in the app folder.  I leave my app folders in dropbox, so whether I'm using my desktop at work or my laptop at home, code and development databases are synced with sqlite. Further, there are no database "users" in sqlite so that's another layer I don't need to worry about.

With Postgres I always have problems; the database doesn't exist, the user doesn't exist, etc. Postgres stores its files separate from the app, which makes it hard. So, how do you develop with Postgres across multiple machines and keep everything in sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) to dump your database to a file, then transfer that file to the other machine, and use [`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) to load it into your other database. Either that or don't depend on having identical data in your various development environments; your migrations should take care of keeping the database structure synchronized and the should patch up existing data as needed.

Comment: Note: `pg_restore` is used when the "custom" format of `pg_dump` is used. For a plain-text dump, just use `psql` to reload the data.